# Crystal Report parameters not working AGAIN

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters, crystal-reports

I am trying to pass a parameter to my report. I have tried different ways but every time it prompts me for a parameter value. I read tons of similar problems but nothing worked for me.

`P_REQUEST_ID` is a static number parameter field used to filter data in the report.

Here is my code:

```
// creating report
var reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
reportDocument.Load("ReportRequestPrice.rpt");

// creating report form 
var dialog = new FormReport();

// not working
var paramFields = new ParameterFields();
var paramField = new ParameterField();
var paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
paramField.Name = "P_REQUEST_ID";
paramDiscreteValue.Value = 1;
// not working
// paramDiscreteValue.Value = "1";
paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
paramFields.Add(paramField);
dialog.reportViewer.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;

/*
// not working
var param = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
param.Value = 1;
reportDocument.ParameterFields["P_REQUEST_ID"].CurrentValues.Add(param);
// not working
//reportDocument.ParameterFields[0].CurrentValues.Add(param);
*/

// setting datasource
reportDocument.SetDataSource(printshopDS);
reportDocument.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(printshopDS);

dialog.reportViewer.ReportSource = reportDocument;            

dialog.ShowDialog(this);
```

Comment: Stating "not working" is not helpful.

Comment: I just fixed a problem accidentally. Crystal report viewer has a property named ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh which was False. Setting it to True made parameters working. I guess somewhere in crystal code refresh is calling, because i tryed to manually refresh report and setting parameters in all possible places without result. PS no error messsages. as i wrote report was asking for parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be replicated with Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2005. The workaround fix is to set the ReportSource property of the CrystalReportViewer first, then you set the parameter values through the property ParameterFieldInfo. Thus, your code should be:

```
// creating report
var reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
reportDocument.Load("ReportRequestPrice.rpt");

// creating report form 
var dialog = new FormReport();

dialog.reportViewer.ReportSource = reportDocument;            

// not working
var paramFields = new ParameterFields();
var paramField = new ParameterField();
var paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
paramField.Name = "P_REQUEST_ID";
paramDiscreteValue.Value = 1;
// not working
// paramDiscreteValue.Value = "1";
paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
paramFields.Add(paramField);
dialog.reportViewer.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;


// setting datasource
reportDocument.SetDataSource(printshopDS);
reportDocument.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(printshopDS);


dialog.ShowDialog(this);
```